# AudioQueueStart return -66681

Tags: ios, recording

When I use `<AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>` to implement a recording function, sometimes there will be unsuccessful recording. The reason is AudioQueueStart returned value -66681. The document says:

> The audio queue has encountered a problem and cannot start

I found documents but I have no idea about that.